# Deleting Contact using Google People API in Google Apps Script returns 404 error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-people-api

I am beating my head against the wall.  I can't figure out why I'm getting a 404 error with this:

```
function SpreadsheetToContactsTest(){
  var people = People.People.getBatchGet({
    resourceNames: 'people/c7926797448542240267',
    personFields: 'metadata'
  });
// Next line is generating the error.
    People.People.deleteContact({
      "resourceName": "people/c7926797448542240267"
    });
  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type `People.People.deleteContact(` in your script, it will show a dialog box that describe the parameter of the method you are trying to use:

**Example:**

deleteContact:

[image]

As described in the image above, `deleteContact` only requires the user to input a string.

To fix the issue in your code, just update the parameter

**From:**

```
People.People.deleteContact({
  "resourceName": "people/c7926797448542240267"
});
```

**To:**

```
People.People.deleteContact("people/c7926797448542240267")
```

### Reference:

- [Method: people.deleteContact](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/deleteContact)

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks.  I'm new to the People API and your answer also helps immensely in understanding the documentation and what parameters are needed elsewhere.